# Can not get value while calling get_json_object() in Spark or Hive

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-spark, hive

json string '{"5.1": 1,"s":2}'

when call

```
select get_json_object('{"5.1": 1,"s":2}',concat("$.","5.1"))
return NULL
```

when call

```
select get_json_object('{"5.1": 1,"s":2}',concat("$.","s"))
return 2
```

It seems that . in 5.1 makes  get_json_object() fail to get the value.

Are there any methods that make get_json_object() work properly?

[hive document](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-get_json_object) shows . is a Child operator, could I disable it?

Comment: have you ever been solved when a number such as 5.1 is used as a key in json string?

Answer (score 1):

`.` is not supported within a key, only `a-z`,`A-Z`,`0-9`,`_`,`-`,`:` and white space character

```
public class UDFJson extends UDF {
  private final Pattern patternKey = Pattern.compile("^([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\:\\s]+).*");

  ... 
}
```

[UDFJson.java](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/ff67cdda1c538dc65087878eeba3e165cf3230f4/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/UDFJson.java)